# Determining whether it matters which subset I pick from my dataset

Tags: statistical-significance, subset

I'm going to simplify my own research problem with the following example:

Lets suppose I have N=40 students in my classroom. I need to select 20 of them to participate in a national math competition. However, I suspect that these students are all similarly intelligent (i.e, it wouldn't matter which 20 students I pick, any group of 20 will give me similar results at the competition).

So, to test my theory, I hold my own math competition. I randomly chose 20 students from my class and tell them to work together and solve the math problems. They finish and they get a certain score. Now, because I'm a cruel but also thorough teacher, I send these students back to their seats, and randomly chose 20 again (some of the same students from the 1st group may be part of this 2nd group). I also wipe out everyones memories of the math test I just gave them and ask them to take it again as a group. This group gets another score.

I repeat this for 100 groups of 20. I have a set of 100 test scores now, 1 for each group of 20 that I randomly drew.

If I just wanted to know whether my theory was true, what statistical test would I perform to determine whether there is any difference in test scores among the groups I picked?

**Edit:** To answer @Kitter Catter, I'll provide a description of my actual data.

I'm working with 3D statistical shape models. Without going into the nitty-gritty details of how they are generated, basically, a statistical shape model in 3D can be understood with a 1D analogy.

Imagine there are two classes of students who take a standardized test. One class had an average of 30% with a standard deviation of 5%. The other had an average of 90% with a standard deviation of 1%. If I randomly picked a student from one of these classes (without knowing which class they belonged to), and asked them their test score, I could easily tell which class they were likely from. For instance, if their score was a 40%:

Using class 1 statistics: 40% = mean(30%) + 2*stdev(5%)

Using class 2 statistics: 40% = mean(90%) + -50*stdev(1%)

In this 1D case, the student is 2 stdev from class 1's mean and 50 from class 2's, so clearly the student is much more likely to have come from class 1.

Statistical shape models in 3D work similarly for image registration tasks. I can try to register a model to an image (based on image features, such as gradients), and determine whether the model that I have fit is statistically reasonable. If it is, I've likely found the location of the shape in the 3D image. If it isn't statistically reasonable, I've either NOT YET found the location, or the location doesn't even exist in the image.

Just like we can describe any student's score in the 1D example as mean + coeff * stdev, we can describe any 3D shape as mean_shape + coeffs * eigenvectors. A statistically "realistic" shape is one that does not deviate significantly from the mean (i.e, the coeffs are not larger than something like 3 standard deviations).

So how do we get a "mean_shape" and the eigenvectors? We have to aggregate a set of 3D shapes (in my dataset, my "shape" is a vertebra), and perform principal component analysis across those shapes. This gives us the mean shape of the vertebra, and the principal directions of variation that the shape varies across the set. This is the statistical shape model.

Basically, my problem is with selecting the set of 3D shapes used to construct the statistical shape model. I have a total of 40 shapes, and I would like to select 20 out of those 40. I believe that it doesn't matter which 20 I select, but I want to statistically verify this.

So what I did is basically generate 100 statistical shape models, each composed of 20 randomly selected shapes out of the 40 shapes. I then used an algorithm I developed to register these shapes to images, and the algorithm spits out an error metric (a single value, the root-mean-square error of the registration).

So basically, as of right now, I have 100 RMSE values corresponding to each group, and I don't know where to go from here. I can see that the values are roughly the same across all 100, but I would like to be able to prove statistically that there is no significant difference across all 100.

Comment: I think you are describing a good procedure for figuring out what the risk or variation of selecting a particular group of students is. To make it into a test it seems like you would need to have some bounds for what is an acceptable risk. (Essentially you can never determine that x=y, but you can get to x = y +/- $\epsilon$) To better evaluate the problem you put up I feel like I'm missing a component. (eg is student performance random? Do students work together linearly or are there interactions that are important?)

Comment: Thanks, just added more information in the edits above

Comment: Based on the description before "Edit": 1) objective is not clear. what is "these students are all similarly intelligent"? 2)proposed method cannot prove anything.